# Use overpass turbo to filter for hotels with > X rooms

Tags: overpass-turbo

I try to find all hotels in my area with more than X rooms.

This is my attempt:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
nwr["tourism"="hotel"]({{bbox}});

(
  way["building"]({{bbox}});
  way["building:shape"!="square"]({{bbox}});
)->.all_buildings;

// filter hotels without square shape
way.all_buildings["tourism"="hotel"]["rooms" > 2];
out geom;
```

**Error**:

> An error occurred while executing the Overpass Query! The Overpass API
> returned the following message:
>
> Error: line 11: parse error: '!', '~', '=', '!=', or ']' expected -
> '>' found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>` character is for recursing down, not greater than.

You can look at this post to see how value operators work:

https://dev.overpass-api.de/blog/numbers.html

In short, you have to use a numerical comparator by using this line at the end of your code:

```
// filter hotels without square shape
way.all_buildings["tourism"="hotel"][rooms](if:t["rooms"]>4);
out geom;
```

(see also question [Using Overpass Turbo to return all peaks over certain elevation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249597/using-overpass-turbo-to-return-all-peaks-over-certain-elevation))